# How do I transform my data when only some treatments are not normal

Tags: r, normal-distribution, anova

I've run a shapiro-wilks test on my data to determine its normality, however the results show that some of the treatments are not normal (P<0.05). Do I transform all of the data, or do I just transform the data for the treatments that are not normal.

I have tried transforming the data, however none of them are enough to make them normal. I am also unsure whether to be transforming all of the data or just the treatment data.

```
tapply(Mutalau$yield,Mutalau$type,shapiro.test)
$`1`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.86025, p-value = 0.19


$`2`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.92557, p-value = 0.5463


$`3`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.69923, p-value = 0.006067


$`4`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.76799, p-value = 0.02971


$`5`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.87673, p-value = 0.2544


$`6`

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  X[[i]]
W = 0.78526, p-value = 0.04313
```

Comment: You are doing multiple testing. This inflates your alpha error.

Comment: I have used square-root and log10 on the data to transform it, but the p value remains less than 0.05 (not normal)

Comment: What is your purpose for requiring normality?

Comment: You don't say what kind of analysis you are doing. If 'treatments' are predictor variables in a regression, as I believe @MatthewDrury may be thinking, then it is the _residuals_ that need to be nearly normal.

Comment: This is in general a difficult question and the answer is to "try to really understand your data" and there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to transform your data, then you should apply the same transformation to all the groups in your response variable. (You generally do not transform your predictor variable.)

Before you transform your data it might be worth checking the actual distributions of your variables (using the `hist()` function in R). Tests for normality, like the Shapiro-Wilk, will preform differently depending on the sample size. For example the Shapiro-Wilk test can give a significant value with (very) large sample sizes that are only slightly different from a normal distribution.

Your question and example do not give enough detail to give specific advice for your analysis, but it might be worth to use a [non-parametric test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics), or running a parametric test and [checking the normality of your residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test#Applications).

Comment: You begin with a very specific statement "If you are planning to transform your data, then you should apply the same transformation to all the variables in your analysis." and end with the somewhat contradictory "Your question and example do not give enough detail to give specific advice for your analysis, ...." I think you may be right the second time.

Comment: Why is it necessary to apply the *same* transformation to all variables? If my response is a proportion and my predictor is an income, I might be inclined to take the log of the income and the arcsin-sqrt of the proportion; taking the arcsin-sqrt of income won't work and taking the log of the proportion wouldn't achieve what the arcsin sqrt was for.